# Angular 2+ set ngModules avoid repeating code

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to make my app more organized so i created a few modules (auth, admin, main), that's fine but i don't understand a few things.. i have the same imports in every module:

```js
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

How can i avoid to being repetitive? Maybe importing all this in main app.module and then exports? And how can i implements lazy loading through this structure...? Thanks in advance

Comment: When a new module is created it acts as a different sub project in a project. like it has its own environment.This is based on my knowledge level might not be the right answer

Comment: You can create a utility module and then import and export whatever you need it that. Then, import the utility module in all the modules that you create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create 'core-module' and import all basic and required component/modules to it and import 'core-module' to other modules.

Same way create 'shared-module' and put common features to it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Plus : import core-module to app-module only once. that will be available to all modules.